# showing $(\arctan(z))' = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$ is true for $z\in C$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I wish to show that $(\arctan(z))' = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$ is true for $z\in C$. I've found, after some algebra, $$ \arctan(z) = \frac{i(e^{iz} + e^{-iz})}{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}} \Rightarrow \arctan(z)' = \frac{4}{e^{2iz}-2+e^{-2iz}}$$
then using $z=x+iy$,
$$\frac{4}{e^{2ix-2y} +e^{-2ix+2y}-2} = \frac{4}{(e^{-2y}+e^{2y})cos(2x) +(e^{-2y} - e^{2y})i\sin{2x} -2})$$
then using $\sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and $\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$,
$$\frac{4}{e^{-2y}e^{iz}+e^{2y}e^{-iz}-2} = \frac{4}{e^{-3y}e^{ix} + e^{3y}e^{-ix}-2}   $$

I cannot get past this point, nor do I know if I'm even on the right path. This problem is a metric ton of algebra, but if you have a hint or solution or spot a misstep, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: $\tan(z)=\dfrac{i(e^{-iz}-e^{iz})}{e^{-iz}+e^{iz}}$, and $\arctan(z)$, though sometimes written $\tan^{-1}(z)$ is different from $1/\tan(z)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the wrong path.

$\dfrac1{\tan z}=\dfrac{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}$, but that is different from $\arctan(z)$.

To show $(\arctan(z))'=\dfrac1{1+z^2}$, start from $\arctan(z)=\theta\implies z=\tan\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method would be to use the power series expansion of arctan to show it converges and use normal derivation.

Answer (score 1):

No need to resort to complex exponentials here; of course it is understood we stay away from singularities.

With

$y(z) = \arctan z, \tag 1$

we have

$z(y) = \tan y, \tag 2$

whence

$z'(y)= (\sec^2 y); \tag 3$

next, we exploit the identity

$\sec^2 y = 1 + \tan^2 y \tag 4$

to write

$z'(y) = (1 + \tan^2 y), \tag 5$

or *via* (2),

$z'(y) = (1 + z^2); \tag 5$

thus,

$(\arctan z)' = y'(z) = \dfrac{1}{z'(y)} = \dfrac{1}{1 + z^2},  \tag 6$

$OE\Delta$.